# I want to get multiple repeating lines from a long txt file (~20k lines)

Tags: python, text, line

I have a long text file with 20k+ lines. There are four distinct patterns which identify the beginning of the lines I want to write to a file. These lines are repeated in the entry file. There are lines which don't start with one of those patterns, these lines shall be skipped. I want to grab the lines starting with the four patterns in order and write them to a file-output in the same order as in the base file.

For example:

> random text
>
> specific start of the first line, random text A
>
> random text B
>
> specific start of the second line, random text C
>
> random text D
>
> etc.

I want the output seems like:

> specific start of the first line, random text A
>   specific start of the second line, random text C

I was thinking about reg-exp, but I'm quite unfamiliar with them. I thought maybe a line-by-line executed function could be better, and maybe even faster. The important thing is, I must retain the original line order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open("input_file",r)
outfile = open("out_file",w)
specific_start = ["specific start pattern1","specific start 
pattern2","specific start pattern3","specific start pattern4"]
for line in file:

    if not  line.startswith(specific_start[0],specific_start[1],specific_start[2],specific_start[3]):
         continue
    else:
         outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: <!-- language: lang-py -->
`path = "c:\\path..."
file = open(path + "out.txt", "r")
outfile = open(path + "filtered.txt", "w")
specific_start = ["specific start pattern1","specific start pattern2","ssp3","ssp4", "ssp5"]
for line in file:

 if not  (line.startswith(specific_start[0]) or line.startswith(specific_start[1]) or line.startswith(specific_start[2]) or line.startswith(specific_start[3]) or line.startswith(specific_start[4])):
  continue
 else:
  outfile.write(line)
  print(line)`
Its just write the 1st specific start and dont write to file. How to format code property?

Comment: See, the example, it works. I guess there is an issue with writing the file. y =['a1e','e','d','e','a2b']
for l in y:
 if not (l.startswith(x[0]) or l.startswith(x[1])): 
  continue 
 else:  
  print(l)

Comment: it did not work - I fixed the indentation, now it should ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use string's method startswith() to check if the beginning of the line is what you want.

This will write all lines from input.txt, beginning with "aaaa", to output.txt:

```
wanted = "aaaa"

with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in, open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith(wanted):
            f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: @jamylak Fixed.